# Authenticate beacon calls from websites

Tags: javascript, authentication, tracking

These days most sites drop tracking beacons (ComScore, Nielsen) to track different metrics like page view, click, user count etc. When such a beacon call reaches ComScore server how does the server detect which page has fired this beacon ?

For example, suppose a person has two sites `nice.com` and `badsite.com`. The site `nice.com` contains good content but traffic to the site is really low. On the other hand `badsite.com` contains adult pirated content and is very popular. Now the person wants to show inflated page view for his `nice.com` site, so he deploys a javascript code on `badsite.com`. This malicious JS snippet tampers the ComScore beacon and provides the identity as `nice.com`.

My question is how ComScore or Alexa prevent this kind of fraud ? Is there HTTP header or any other attribute present in the call that the tracking server can use to authenticate that beacon was actually fired from `nice.com` ?